# How to search for a very long term? (longer than the maximum nGram-size)

Tags: elasticsearch, n-gram

I have an elasticsearch field, which uses nGrams. It is basically defined like this:

```
index.analysis.filter.gram_filter.type = nGram
index.analysis.filter.gram_filter.min_gram = 2
index.analysis.filter.gram_filter.max_gram = 15
```

Searching for terms, longer than 15 characters is therefore not possible. If I store these value:

```
Text:  BananaAppleOrange
Bytes: 12345678901234567
```

Then I can find that value by searching for: `BananaAppleOran`, but not by searching for `BananaAppleOrange`.

How do I search for terms, that are longer than the maximum nGram-size (15 in my case)?

Comment: ngram works like a sliding window, your index does not contain term `BananaAppleOrange`

Comment: Also, you can consider `_all` field to refine your results (unless it is turned off).

Comment: @YuriyTseretyan

"ngram works like a sliding window, your index does not contain term BananaAppleOrange"

can you explain why the search for "BananaAppleOrange" does not yield results, please?